# Execution of find_in_set() in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, operator-precedence

Here is my screenshot which shows the query executed with the command `find_in_set`.

It executes the set of values in a particular row only. I want to execute all of the values in a table that match `find_in_set` command in a single query.

Take a look at my code :

```
select * from shirts;
+----+--------------+------------------------------------+
| id | colors       | days                               |
+----+--------------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | 1,2,5,12,15  | monday, friday, thursday           |
|  2 | 1,5,12,15,30 | tuesday,monday                     |
|  3 | 2,5,11,15,28 | monday, friday,wednesday ,thursday |
|  4 | 1,2,7,12,15  | tuesday,monday                     |
|  5 | 2,4,8,12,15  | tuesday,monday                     |
+----+--------------+------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from shirts where find_in_set('5',colors) or find_in_set('30',colors) or find_in_set('30', colors) and find_in_set('monday',days) or  find_in_set('tuesday',days);
+----+--------------+------------------------------------+
| id | colors       | days                               |
+----+--------------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | 1,2,5,12,15  | monday, friday, thursday           |
|  2 | 1,5,12,15,30 | tuesday,monday                     |
|  3 | 2,5,11,15,28 | monday, friday,wednesday ,thursday |
|  4 | 1,2,7,12,15  | tuesday,monday                     |
|  5 | 2,4,8,12,15  | tuesday,monday                     |
+----+--------------+------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from shirts where find_in_set('5',colors) or find_in_set('30',colors) and find_in_set('monday',days) or  find_in_set('tuesday',days);
+----+--------------+------------------------------------+
| id | colors       | days                               |
+----+--------------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | 1,2,5,12,15  | monday, friday, thursday           |
|  2 | 1,5,12,15,30 | tuesday,monday                     |
|  3 | 2,5,11,15,28 | monday, friday,wednesday ,thursday |
|  4 | 1,2,7,12,15  | tuesday,monday                     |
|  5 | 2,4,8,12,15  | tuesday,monday                     |
+----+--------------+------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I choosed `5` and `30` in **colors** and `monday , friday` in **days** but it displays only the `1` and `3` row.

Can anyone rectify my problem?

Comment: where is your screenshot?

Comment: improved formatting, fixed grammar, added tag

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in boolean algebra, `AND` binds tighter than `OR`.

There is a [default order of precedence of these operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html).

When you write this:

```
select * from shirts where A or B and C or D
```

It's always as if you had used parentheses like this:

```
select * from shirts where A or (B and C) or D
```

But you want it to act like this:

```
select * from shirts where (A or B) and (C or D)
```

So you will have to write the query with explicit parentheses to override the default order of precedence of `AND` vs. `OR`.

The problem has nothing to do with using find_in_set(). It's just a boolean algebra mistake.